# WCF differences between .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5

Tags: wcf

What are the differences between WCF using .NET 3.0 versus .NET 3.5?  I need to understand what has improved between the .NET versions.

Comment: The list could be very large. Can you be more specific about what you want to k now, and why you want to know it? Are you trying to decide whether or not to upgrade to .NET 3.5 SP1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in 3.5 you get

- WCF and WF Integration—Workflow Services
- Durable Services
- WCF Web Programming Model
- WCF Syndication
- WCF and Partial Trust
- WCF and ASP.NET AJAX Integration
- Web Services Interoperability

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx for details

if you apply the .NET 3.5 SP1 you get

- Significant scalability improvements (5-10x) in Web-hosted application scenarios
- Support for using ADO.NET Entity Framework entities in WCF contracts
- API usability improvements with DataContract Serializers, and with the UriTemplate and WCF web programming models
- Enhanced TestClient support within VS 2008 SP1
- New Hosting Wizard in VS 2008 SP1 for WCF Service Projects
- Improved debugging support in partial trust scenarios